# Unexpected latency in Java Sound during long executions

Tags: java, javasound

I'm writing a audio chat application in Java and I'm experiencing some latency/delays that mostly shows up if the application is left running for a while.

I recreated the problem in the below sample application. It simply loops sound from the microphone to the speaker. Initially it behaves as expected. When you press the button and speak into the microphone you hear yourself in the speaker with a tiny delay. However if the program is left running for a while (a week) then that delay is increased to several seconds.

I tested with different headsets. I tested with Java 8, 9, 10 and it consistently displays the same behaviour. I also experimented with drain() and flush() and so on but the only thing that gets rid of the delay is to close and recreate the TargetDataLine. Recreating the line is however not an option for my application since it takes to long and audio is unavailable while you recreate the line.

Is this a known limitation or am I doing something wrong? Very thankful for any insight or ideas!

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

/**
 * Created by asa on 2018-04-03.
 */
public class Main {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
      String title = "";
      if (args.length > 0) {
         title = args[0];
      }
      String mixerName = "USB”; // Part of the name of my headset
      if (args.length > 1) {
         mixerName = args[1];
      }
      AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000f,
                                           16,
                                           1,
                                           true,
                                           false);
      DataLine.Info targetInfo = new TargetDataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
      TargetDataLine mic = null;
      for (Mixer.Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
         if (info.getName().contains(mixerName) && !info.getName().contains("Port")) {
            Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
            if (m.isLineSupported(targetInfo)) {
               mic = (TargetDataLine) m.getLine(targetInfo);
               break;
            }
         }
      }
      mic.open(format, 1280);
      mic.start();

      DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
      SourceDataLine speaker = null;
      for (Mixer.Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
         if (info.getName().contains(mixerName) && !info.getName().contains("Port")) {
            Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
            if (m.isLineSupported(sourceInfo)) {
               speaker = (SourceDataLine) m.getLine(sourceInfo);
               break;
            }
         }
      }
      speaker.open(format, 8000);
      speaker.start();

      MicRunnable micRunnable = new MicRunnable(mic, speaker);
      new Thread(micRunnable).start();

      Frame.show(title, new Frame.PttListener() {
         @Override
         public void press() {
            micRunnable.start();
         }

         @Override
         public void release() {
            micRunnable.stop();
         }
      });
   }

   private static class MicRunnable implements Runnable {
      private final TargetDataLine _mic;
      private final SourceDataLine _speaker;

      private final Object runLock = new Object();
      private volatile boolean running = false;

      public MicRunnable(TargetDataLine mic, SourceDataLine speaker) {
         _mic = mic;
         _speaker = speaker;
      }

      public void start() {
         synchronized (runLock) {
            running = true;
            runLock.notify();
         }
      }

      public void stop() {
         synchronized (runLock) {
            running = false;
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
         while (true) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[640];
            _mic.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            if (running) {//tPeakGain(bytes) > 300) {
               _speaker.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private static class Frame extends JFrame {

      interface PttListener {
         void press();
         void release();
      }

      private Frame(String title, PttListener listener) {
         setTitle(title);
         JPanel content = new JPanel();

         JButton pttButton = new JButton("PTT");
         pttButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
               listener.press();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
               listener.release();
            }
         });

         content.add(pttButton);

         setContentPane(content);
         setSize(300, 100);
      }

      public static void show(String title, Frame.PttListener pttListener) {
         new Frame(title, pttListener).setVisible(true);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The way you describe it, this sounds like a memory/gc problem. Have you tried logging GC via the JVM flag `-XX:+PrintGC` to confirm or refute this (alternatively, use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io))? Long full GCs when you notice the delays would be a strong hint. It should not be a big thing, but first thing I'd do is move `byte[] bytes = new byte[640];` before `while(true) {` Repeatedly allocating a new buffer in an infinite loop is always a bad idea. While you're at it, you should pay attention to what `_mic.read(...)` returns.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this @hendrik. I have launched a new set of tests that includes fixes based on your feedback. They've been running over the weekend but it usually takes longer for the problem to manifest so I don’t know yet if it will make a difference. To be clear though when the latency shows up it is not an intermittent problem. The audio is consistently delayed until the program is restarted.

Comment: The new tests incorporation your pointers @hendrik show the same latency problem. I checked on GC with VisualVM and it sits at 0%. Memory and CPU usage is small.

Comment: GC is not measured in %. Not sure what you looked at. Did you log GC with `-XX:+PrintGC`?

Comment: @hendrik VisualVM reports GC as a percentage of the used CPU. Which seem to be 0% for my test application. I also implemented a version that does not allocate any new memory in the loop and I still get the same delays as the original version of the test app.

Comment: CPU usage is not what your looking for. Garbage collection is of interest. You must log GC, if you want to make that it is not the problem.

Comment: I looked at the GC using the trace option you suggested @hendrik. The original version of the program GCs once every half hour. A fixed version that does not allocate anything in the loop only GCs once. But both version displays the latency problems after a couple of days so does not seem to be related to GC activity.

Comment: Sounds like GC isn't the issue here.